# Why git does not contain the latest Linux kernel?

Tags: git, linux-kernel

I can see that the latest version is `4.4-rc8` however my `git pull ; git log` says: `Linux 4.4-rc6`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Show us your output for `git remote -v`.

Comment: `origin git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git (fetch)`
`origin git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git (push)`

Comment: You are using stable tree but you want the mainline one (Linus Torvald's tree). Use this remote instead: `git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git`. This is mainline version of kernel. Doing `git tag` you should be able to see `4.4-rc8`.

Comment: Basically what you want is to go to [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/). Then you choose which version do you want, stable or mainline (and you can see last tag for each version there). Then you click **browse** for chosen version, go to **summary** tab. There you can see last version tag and link for cloning (at the bottom).

Comment: ok, thanks, could you please put it as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your output for `git remote -v` command shows that you are using **stable** kernel tree:

```
git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git
```

It doesn't contain the latest kernel version. For the latest kernel you need to use **mainline** kernel (Linus Torvald's tree). Use this remote to do so:

```
git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
```

With this remote you should be able to see last version (currently it's `4.4-rc8`) in the output of `git tag` command.

Basically, to obtain kernel you should:

- visit [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/)
- choose which kernel version you want, stable or mainline (you can see version number for each kernel there)
- click **browse** link for chosen version
- go to the **summary** tab.

There you can see last version tags and link for cloning (at the bottom).